Sidebar animation on width messes with content inside of it because of available space
I'm creating a web app using Vue and Tailwind. However, since this is my first dabble with Tailwind I am running into issues that seemingly seem quite trivial but I (and copilot :-) ) cannot seem to fix it.
This is the HTML:
<div id="app" class="bg-gray-100 text-black h-screen">
  <div class="flex gap-x-8 justify-center max-w-screen-xl mx-auto p-4">
    <aside :class="{ 'w-72': isExpanded, 'w-24': !isExpanded }"
    class="bg-white h-screen p-4 pt-8 relative duration-300 rounded-xl flex flex-col transition-width">
      <button @click="toggleSidebar" class="cursor-pointer absolute -right-5 top-7 transform-gpu transition duration-200" >{{isExpanded ? 'close' : 'open'}}</button>
      
      <!-- Menu items        -->
      <div class="pt-12">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item of menuItems" class="flex items-center align-center px-3 py-3 gap-x-4 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer">
             <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            <span
            :class="{ 'opacity-0 w-0': !isExpanded }"
            class="origin-left duration-200 w-auto transition-width"
            >{{ item.label }}</span
          </li>
            
          </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <main class="p-8 rounded-xl grow bg-white">
      <h2 class="text-xl font-bold mb-2">Hi {{person}}</h2>
       <article class="w-40 h-40 rounded bg-gray-700"></article>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

And the sample app:
const { createApp } = Vue;

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      person: "Codepen User!",
      isExpanded: true,
      menuItems: [{icon: '', label: "Dashboard"}, {icon: '', label: "A long menu item"}, {icon: '', label: "Settings"}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSidebar(event) {
      this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
    },
  }
}).mount("#app");

As you can see, when clicking the low effort "open" and "close" text, the sidebar minimizes. However, when doing this, the text of the menu items goes into multiple lines depending on the width of the parent animation. This is undesired. I would like it to be smooth where the text is always the same line.
Here's a simple codepen with the same code: https://codepen.io/duncanteege/pen/MWRQgqy

Putting white-space: pre on the li would be a simple solution - if it is guaranteed, that none of the items will be more than one line of text to begin with (even at lower viewports sizes.)

@CBroe that indeed does fix it for single lines. I wonder what the solution would be if an item would span multiple lines.

@dunct maybe use truncate so it never spans multiple lines?

"I wonder what the solution would be if an item would span multiple lines." - you could try and explicitly set the width of the li elements to their current width in open mode, when collapsing the side bar gets triggered.

@dunct for multi-line elements, you would set a height and min-width without the white-space: pre on li and more importantly get rid of the w-0 for the span class when not expanded
